# How modal verbs change while converting active voice to passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, modal-verbs, active-voice

> We can buy electrical appliances from Amazon.

1. Electrical appliances can be bought from Amazon.
2. Electrical appliances could be bought from Amazon.

Which among the two is the correct passive voice of the given sentence?

Comment: Why do you think one of them is "incorrect". Have you looked up "can" and "could" in a dictionary?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because it was a multiple-choice question. Both options were given. The key says only the 1st option is correct.

Comment: Look up the meanings of "can" and "could" and you'll understand why the former is preferred. Your problem might lie in confusing the passive voice with reported speech (indirect).

Comment: @Mari-LouA I see. I actually thought both passive voice and reported speech were the same. I'd learned that 'can' becomes 'could' in indirect speech. Would you mind explaining that?

Comment: Why do you think the modal would change when switching to passive voice? It doesn't. If you are referring to past time, then preterite "could" is correct, otherwise present tense "can".

Comment: @BillJ I'd learned that 'can' becomes 'could' in indirect speech.

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser: "indirect speech" and "passive" are two completely independent constructions, that have nothing in common (except, in a general sense, that the form of a verb may change). They can occur separately or both together.

Comment: @BillJ I thought indirect speech and passive voice were the same. Could you explain that a bit? Or perhaps provide a source where I can read the difference? (English is neither my native language nor I'm a student of the subject. I have to learn this only to tackle an entrance exam, so I actually don't know where to search or what to look for, and I'm prone to many basic mistakes, unfortunately.

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser Your question makes no reference to indirect speech. This is simply a case of passive voice past time "could" vs "can" elsewhere. One exception, though, is where it is part of a conditional construction, as in "It would be surprising if electrical appliances could not be bought from Amazon", where "could" expresses modal remoteness.

Comment: I think I see why @Curiouserandcuriouser is getting confused about "**can** becoming **could** in reported speech". If John said *I **can** do it,* that would very often be "backshifted" as *John said that he **could** do it* (but there's nothing wrong with the "unbackshifted" version *John said that he **can** do it*, provided he can *still* do it at the later time when his speech is being reported; backshifting isn't *obligatory*).

Answer (score 3):

As Huddleston and Pullum (2002) state, "could" is the past tense (or rather the preterite) of "can." Since your goal is just to make it passive, not to change the tense, the correct answer is:

> Electrical appliances can be bought from Amazon.

Comment: "could be bought" e.g. "I could buy it", the modal verb *could* is also used for the present, it has a different meaning from "can be bought" that's basically it in a nutshell. "Easy" questions should not be answered, especially ones whose answer can be found in a dictionary. EDIT You answer states *not to change the tense*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's still the preterite; it's just that the preterite can be used to indicate modal remoteness, not just past time.

Comment: I was commenting on the assertion *not to change the tense*, *We could buy it online* (It could be bought online) has a different meaning to "We can buy it " (it can be bought online), there is no shift in tense. A shift in tense is normally required when  we use reported speech. I don't know why I'm saying this to you, as you know  the grammar far better than I do. But the OP's confusion lies there. See the comments under the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Could you provide a source where I can read about the difference between the two? (English is neither my native language nor I'm a student of the subject. I have to learn this only to tackle an entrance exam, so I actually don't know where to search or what to look for, and I'm prone to many basic mistakes, unfortunately.)

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser you have the Internet. Type [*"indirect speech" English grammar*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22indirect+speech%22+%22English+grammar%22&sxsrf=AJOqlzVGU9QXVObpJtrgyxj7WSg2Eb6pzg%3A1678801669415&ei=BXsQZOHzGL6Rxc8P4aqw2A8&ved=0ahUKEwihip3Jx9v9AhW-SPEDHWEVDPsQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22indirect+speech%22+%22English+grammar%22&gs_lcp=gws-wiz-serp) and then do the same for "passive voice" English grammar, and you'll find all the help you need.

Comment: It's not related to reported speech per se, except insofar as that speech can be backshifted (and thus result in a change of tense). Compare: "He says he can walk ten miles easily" and "Five years ago he could run a marathon, but he can't anymore."

Comment: There is no sense in confusing the OP with a grammar framework/terminology they won’t have access to.